# default boost tests returning false

Tags: c++, unit-testing, boost, visual-studio-2015

I have just downloded and intalled Boost Unit Test Adapter, and followed the online official manual as https://github.com/etas/vs-boost-unit-test-adapter/wiki/User-Manual.

However the tests are returning false. I have copied my print screens as below, I am not sure as to why the following is occuring.

Any ideas? 
    [image]
    [image]
    [image]
    [image]
    [image]

Comment: Hint: you want to be really really conservative about posting screen shots here. I agree that some of them make sense, but *anything* that is pure text (like that last console output) ... you post here as text, not as image!

Comment: @GhostCat understood, il keep that in mind for the future! Any thoughts on my above issue?

Comment: @reyyez - I would heed, and not just keep in mind for the future, GhostCat's advice to replace screen shots with text where possible (code, error/console output etc.)